# Fedex Webservices XML Error

Tags: xmlhttprequest, xsd, fedex

Im sending a XML request to Fedex Webservices to create a COD label, using EXPRESS services. The following XML request works for GROUND services, but it doesnt for EXPRESS.
I get following, here's the debug information. Where exactly is the package level?

Error confirming shipment: 2245 (COD can not be specified at package level for Express Shipments)

```
--------------------------------------------------
Debug Information
--------------------------------------------------
debugMode = 1

--------------------------------------------------
XML Sent
--------------------------------------------------
<ns:ProcessShipmentRequest xmlns:ns="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v10" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v10 ShipService v10.xsd">
   <ns:WebAuthenticationDetail>
      <ns:UserCredential>
         <ns:Key>XXXX</ns:Key>
         <ns:Password>XXXX</ns:Password>
      </ns:UserCredential>
   </ns:WebAuthenticationDetail>
   <ns:ClientDetail>
      <ns:AccountNumber>XXXX</ns:AccountNumber>
      <ns:MeterNumber>XXXX</ns:MeterNumber>
   </ns:ClientDetail>
   <ns:TransactionDetail>
      <ns:CustomerTransactionId>CreatePendingRequest</ns:CustomerTransactionId>
   </ns:TransactionDetail>
   <ns:Version>
      <ns:ServiceId>ship</ns:ServiceId>
      <ns:Major>10</ns:Major>
      <ns:Intermediate>0</ns:Intermediate>
      <ns:Minor>0</ns:Minor>
   </ns:Version>
   <ns:RequestedShipment>
      <ns:ShipTimestamp>2012-11-13T18:59:09-07:00</ns:ShipTimestamp>
      <ns:DropoffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</ns:DropoffType>
      <ns:ServiceType>STANDARD_OVERNIGHT</ns:ServiceType>
      <ns:PackagingType>YOUR_PACKAGING</ns:PackagingType>
      <ns:Shipper>
         <ns:Contact>
            <ns:PersonName>John Doe</ns:PersonName>
            <ns:CompanyName>Company</ns:CompanyName>
            <ns:PhoneNumber>1123456789</ns:PhoneNumber>
         </ns:Contact>
         <ns:Address>
            <ns:StreetLines>1234 Street Name</ns:StreetLines>
            <ns:City>City</ns:City>
            <ns:StateOrProvinceCode>FL</ns:StateOrProvinceCode>
            <ns:PostalCode>12345</ns:PostalCode>
            <ns:CountryCode>US</ns:CountryCode>
         </ns:Address>
      </ns:Shipper>
      <ns:Recipient>
         <ns:Contact>
            <ns:PersonName>NAME</ns:PersonName>
            <ns:CompanyName>COMPANY</ns:CompanyName>
            <ns:PhoneNumber>0123456789</ns:PhoneNumber>
         </ns:Contact>
         <ns:Address>
            <ns:StreetLines>STE</ns:StreetLines>
            <ns:City>CITY NAME</ns:City>
            <ns:StateOrProvinceCode>FL</ns:StateOrProvinceCode>
            <ns:PostalCode>12345</ns:PostalCode>
            <ns:CountryCode>US</ns:CountryCode>
         </ns:Address>
      </ns:Recipient>
      <ns:ShippingChargesPayment>
         <ns:PaymentType>SENDER</ns:PaymentType>
         <ns:Payor>
            <ns:AccountNumber>XXXX</ns:AccountNumber>
            <ns:CountryCode>US</ns:CountryCode>
         </ns:Payor>
      </ns:ShippingChargesPayment>
      <ns:SpecialServicesRequested>
      </ns:SpecialServicesRequested>
      <ns:LabelSpecification>
         <ns:LabelFormatType>COMMON2D</ns:LabelFormatType>
         <ns:ImageType>PNG</ns:ImageType>
         <ns:LabelStockType>PAPER_8.5X11_TOP_HALF_LABEL</ns:LabelStockType>
      </ns:LabelSpecification>
      <ns:RateRequestTypes>LIST</ns:RateRequestTypes>
      <ns:PackageCount>1</ns:PackageCount>
      <ns:RequestedPackageLineItems>
         <ns:Weight>
            <ns:Units>LB</ns:Units>
            <ns:Value>1</ns:Value>
         </ns:Weight>
         <ns:Dimensions>
            <ns:Length>5</ns:Length>
            <ns:Width>5</ns:Width>
            <ns:Height>5</ns:Height>
            <ns:Units>IN</ns:Units>
         </ns:Dimensions>
         <ns:SpecialServicesRequested>
            <ns:SpecialServiceTypes>COD</ns:SpecialServiceTypes>
            <ns:CodDetail>
               <ns:CodCollectionAmount>
                  <ns:Currency>USD</ns:Currency>
                  <ns:Amount>115.00</ns:Amount>
               </ns:CodCollectionAmount>
               <ns:CollectionType>CASH</ns:CollectionType>
               <ns:ReferenceIndicator>TRACKING</ns:ReferenceIndicator>
            </ns:CodDetail>
         </ns:SpecialServicesRequested>
      </ns:RequestedPackageLineItems>
   </ns:RequestedShipment>
</ns:ProcessShipmentRequest>



--------------------------------------------------
XML Response
--------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<v10:ProcessShipmentReply xmlns:v10="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v10"><v10:HighestSeverity xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">ERROR</v10:HighestSeverity><v10:Notifications xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><v10:Severity>ERROR</v10:Severity><v10:Source>ship</v10:Source><v10:Code>2245</v10:Code><v10:Message>COD can not be specified at package level for Express Shipments</v10:Message><v10:LocalizedMessage>COD can not be specified at package level for Express Shipments</v10:LocalizedMessage></v10:Notifications><ns:TransactionDetail xmlns:ns="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v10" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><ns:CustomerTransactionId>CreatePendingRequest</ns:CustomerTransactionId></ns:TransactionDetail><ns:Version xmlns:ns="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v10" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><ns:ServiceId>ship</ns:ServiceId><ns:Major>10</ns:Major><ns:Intermediate>0</ns:Intermediate><ns:Minor>0</ns:Minor></ns:Version></v10:ProcessShipmentReply>


--------------------------------------------------
PHP Information
--------------------------------------------------
5.3.18

--------------------------------------------------
cURL Return Information
--------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 14 Nov 2012 01:59:02 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2
Content-Length: 1167
x-wily-servlet: Clear appServerIp=204.135.252.191&agentName=ESB-servicebus-1&servletName=HttpTransportServlet&servletResponseTime=119&agentHost=qje20222&agentProcess=WebLogic
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
x-wily-info: Clear guid=FCA41585CC87FCBF0C2A8683C9B05C6A
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<v10:ProcessShipmentReply xmlns:v10="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v10"><v10:HighestSeverity xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">ERROR</v10:HighestSeverity><v10:Notifications xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><v10:Severity>ERROR</v10:Severity><v10:Source>ship</v10:Source><v10:Code>2245</v10:Code><v10:Message>COD can not be specified at package level for Express Shipments</v10:Message><v10:LocalizedMessage>COD can not be specified at package level for Express Shipments</v10:LocalizedMessage></v10:Notifications><ns:TransactionDetail xmlns:ns="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v10" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><ns:CustomerTransactionId>CreatePendingRequest</ns:CustomerTransactionId></ns:TransactionDetail><ns:Version xmlns:ns="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v10" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><ns:ServiceId>ship</ns:ServiceId><ns:Major>10</ns:Major><ns:Intermediate>0</ns:Intermediate><ns:Minor>0</ns:Minor></ns:Version></v10:ProcessShipmentReply>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using a different CollectionType? CASH may not be an option for Express (only for Ground). Try one of the others, like ANY or GUARANTEED_FUNDS and see if you get better results. Fedex can return 'less than helpful' error messages that don't really point you in the right direction. (You might also need to leave out ReferenceIndicator for express - I think that might only be available for Ground)

Comment: One other wild guess - move that SpecialServiceRequested section out of the RequestedPackageLineItems section. Up a level.

Comment: also tried that, the only way it works is if I remove <ns:SpecialServiceTypes>COD</ns:SpecialServiceTypes>, however if I do that, it doesnt treat the shipment as COD